# zabbix import trigger template

Tags: linux, monitoring, cisco, zabbix

i am importing a zabbix template, the items load successfully

snippet of the xml template:

```
      <triggers>
        <trigger>
          <description>PING response on Vlan1</description>
          <type>1</type>
          <expression>{11.11.11.11:icmpping['11.11.11.11'].last(0)}=0</expression>
          <status>0</status>
          <priority>0</priority>
          <comments>Interface: Vlan1 is down</comments>
        </trigger>
      </triggers>
    </host>
  </hosts>
</zabbix_export>
```

but when it reaches the trigger section while importing it gives this error:

```
Added new item Template_Test_Router_Ping:icmpping[11.11.11.11,3,25,68,500]
[ CTrigger::create ] No permissions !
```

any idea which permissions its referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  parent template didn't exist, could be various reason such as linked with other template.

why dont you try Importing template element only and then import everything doing same for the host, First imported hosts and then imported everything else. (Importing the base "Elements" only in the first import then, Importing the everything else the second import.)

Hope this helps